AWS : Deregister UnHealthy IPs from Registered Targets (Target Group) using GitHub action workflow is not working
Problem Statement : While Registering new IP in ELB Fargate under Target Group, Old IP went into the Unhealthy status. I want to Deregister old IP automatically with the help of Github actions workflow.
What did I tried so far ?
These are the three steps which I added into the existing workflow file (Added descriptive comments in the below steps for more clarification).
name: List Targets
id: list-targets <!-- Assigns an ID to this step for reference in later steps. -->
env:
  AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN: ${{ inputs.AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN }}
run: |
  aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn $AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN > targets.json <!-- Executes an AWS CLI command to retrieve the target health descriptions for the specified target group and saves the output to targets.json. -->
cat targets.json <!-- Prints the content of `targets.json` to the log for debugging purposes. -->


name: Filter Unused IPs
id: filter-unused-ips <!-- Assigns an ID to this step for reference in later steps. -->
run: |
  jq -r '.TargetHealthDescriptions[] | select(.TargetHealth.State == "unhealthy") | .Target.Id' targets.json > unused-ips.txt <!-- Here, Filter targets where the health state is "unhealthy". Then, Extract the IP addresses of these targets and write the unused IPs to unused-ips.txt. -->
  cat unused-ips.txt <!-- Prints the content of unused-ips.txt to the log for debugging purposes. -->
  if [[ -s unused-ips.txt ]]; then <!-- Checks if unused-ips.txt is non-empty and sets an environment variable unused-ips to true or false accordingly using $GITHUB_ENV. -->
    echo "unused-ips=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  else
    echo "unused-ips=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  fi


name: Deregister Unused IPs
if: env.unused-ips == 'true' <!-- This step will only run if the environment variable unused-ips is set to true. -->
env:
  AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN: ${{ inputs.AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN }}
run: |
  while IFS= read -r IP; do <!-- It reads each IP address from unused-ips.txt and deregisters it from the target group using the AWS CLI. -->
    echo "Deregistering $IP"
    aws elbv2 deregister-targets --target-group-arn $AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN --targets Id=$IP || echo "Failed to deregister $IP"
  done < unused-ips.txt

All these steps in the workflow is working fine without having any issues and I can also see this print statement Deregistering <IP> at the end but somehow IPs are not deregistering from the target groups.
Also, I tried to deregister it via aws-cli from my laptop and command executed successfully but still IP is not deregistering/draining in the AWS console.
echo "Attempting to deregister <IP> from <AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN>"
result=$(aws elbv2 deregister-targets --target-group-arn <AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN> --targets Id=<IP> 2>&1)
echo "Command result: $result"

From above commands, it's prints $result as an empty and not showing any error.
I also verified the IAM policy attached to the user to ensure that attached IAM policy has the required permissions to deregister the target.
I am having this policy attached to the user, and I don't think there is any permission issue.
{
    "Version": "****-**-**",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Can someone help me to understand why unhealthy target group IPs are not deregistering from the AWS console ?

Is locally (not in github actions) the command really deregistering the ip?

@ShaykiAbramczyk How to test it locally ? As IPs are registering in AWS and my github workflow is running whenever there is any push happen into the branch.

Authenticate to your aws account from your laptop and run the commands

@ShaykiAbramczyk Sure, I will check and verify this way as well and will let you know the result.

@ShaykiAbramczyk - I tried to deregister the IP from my mac using aws cli. This command aws elbv2 deregister-targets --target-group-arn $AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN --targets Id=$IP executed successfully and did not received any error. But in AWS tagrget group IP is not deregistering/draining.

I am able to fix this issue by adding a port at the end in deregister-targets command.

Even though the wildcard policy permits all actions, Try to specify the required permissions.
{
  "Version": "****-**-**",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}


I tried this way but it's not working.

Ensure that the target IDs you're trying to deregister are in the correct format. Sometimes, the IDs might include extra characters or might be incorrectly formatted.
